# Write character by character in a String created with malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, pointer-arithmetic

If I have allocated some memory, why can't I write character by character in its position? The following printf doesn't output anything. What am I missing here?

```
int main()
{
        char *newStr = NULL;
        newStr = (char *) malloc ((2) * sizeof(char));
        *newStr = 'a';
        newStr++;
        *newStr = '\0';
        printf("%s", newStr);
}
```

Comment: Simpler form of malloc: `newStr = malloc(2);`. Also, you need `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're shifting your pointer so `printf("%s", newStr);` try to print only the `\0`.

Try this:

```c
    char *newStr = NULL;

    newStr = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    *newStr = 'a';
    newStr++;
    *newStr = '\0';
    newStr--;
    printf("%s", newStr);
```

Or this:

```c
    char *newStr = NULL;
    char *backupedPointer = NULL;

    newStr = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    backupedPointer = newStr;
    *newStr = 'a';
    newStr++;
    *newStr = '\0';
    printf("%s", backupedPointer);
```

And like Matt McNabb says in his comment you should add the `free()` at the end to release the memory you've allocated (one `malloc()` = one `free()`, always) :

```c
    char *newStr = NULL;
    char *backupedPointer = NULL;

    newStr = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    backupedPointer = newStr;
    *newStr = 'a';
    newStr++;
    *newStr = '\0';
    printf("%s", backupedPointer);
    free(backupedPointer);
```

One of the best solutions would be :

```c
    char *newStr = NULL;

    newStr = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    newStr[0] = 'a';
    newStr[1] = '\0';
    printf("%s", newStr);
    free(newStr);
```

Comment: Adding to this, you should `free` anything you `malloc`, so it is a good idea to not change a pointer that is pointing to `malloc`'d space. Make another pointer or use  an integer index instead.